# Paste user defined text using shortcuts in Atom-editor

Tags: atom-editor

I would like to know if it's possible to use shortcuts to paste user defined text in the atom-editor. And if possible I'd like to know how.

An example would be, pressing Alt-Shift-F would paste `\frac{}{}` into the editor.

Comment: Why not use [snippets](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/)?

Comment: Because i wasn't aware those existed before now. Thank you for enlightening me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample that insert html non breakable space with shift+space.

In your init script:

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor', 'custom:html-hard-space',->
  editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor()
  editor.insertText('&nbsp;')
```

In your keynmap:

```
'atom-text-editor:not([mini])':
  'shift-space': 'custom:html-hard-space'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!